# Delete a Node from Linked List using key

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to delete a node from the linked list by given key. The linked list contains the following type of data

```
    List nd = new List ();
    
    nd.insertdata(" Himasha ");
    nd.insertdata(" Chiara ");
    nd.insertdata(" Angel ");
    nd.insertdata(" Niana ");
    nd.insertdata(" Romeli ");
```

This is the method I created to delete a node by given key . But the problem is it alwas deletes the only Value "Chiara"

```
 public void Deleteobj (String name ) {
     Nodo n = Head ;
    
  while(n. equals(name) ){
      n= n.next ;
      
  }
   
 Nodo n1 = n.next ;   //n1 equals the delete node
 n.next = n1.next ;
 System.out.println("The  cancellation value is : "+ n1.data);
   
}
```

### Output

Insert a key for Delete
// my input
: Niana

The  cancellation value is :  Chiara

This is the problem eventhough I wanted to delete the key "Niana "  . always It deletes the key "Chiara"

Answer (score 0):

Well it just takes the second value, the condition `n.equals(name)` will be always `false` for multiple reasons: first of all, `Nodo` and `String` are completely different types, so it's unlikely they will ever be equal. Also, even if you somehow managed to make it true, it makes no sence, why would you make a loop that checks all nodes that are equal to what are you looking for and skip them?

So that's the reason you are getting the output you are getting. The loop breaks at the first run, so your `n` is `head`. You take n1 as `next` of `n`, which is 2nd item, and that's what you print out.

Also it contradicts naming conventions of java code.

There are more problems, but you should fix this first.